# Observable binding to two ICollectionView of same collection

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, collectionviewsource, inotifycollectionchanged

So I'm using `WPF` in the `MVVM` way using `Caliburn.Micro` as a framework.

I have a ViewModel with a ObservableCollection that I need to show twice with different sorting, filtering and grouping.

I'm kind of having a hard time with this supposedly simple action. I normally would do this:

```
private ICollectionView _datagridCollectionView;
public ICollectionView DatagridCollectionView
{
    get
    {
        if (this._datagridCollectionView == null)
        {
            this._datagridCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items);
            using (this._datagridCollectionView.DeferRefresh())
            {
                this._datagridCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                this._datagridCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SortingProperty", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }
        }
        return this._datagridCollectionView;
    }
}
```

And it works fine, it sorts and it's observable.

So I added the second view the same way:

```
private ICollectionView _chartCollectionView;
public ICollectionView ChartCollectionView
{
    get
    {
        if (this._chartCollectionView == null)
        {
            this._chartCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items);
            using (this._chartCollectionView.DeferRefresh())
            {
                this._chartCollectionView.Filter = (p) => { return p.IsChartable; };
            }
        }
        return this._chartCollectionView;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is (likely because I access the default view and thus have the same reference) that all sorting/filtering is done to both views.

So I tried to do new instance of `ICollectionView` but `CollectionView` should not be used and `ListCollectionView` is made for lists and not `IEnumarbles` so I even if I use the `ToList()` method the views are no longer Observable.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried following the suggestion documented in the remarks of the documentation of the `CollectionView` class? *To create a collection view for a collection that only implements `IEnumerable`, create a `CollectionViewSource` object, add your collection to the `Source` property, and get the collection view from the `View` property.*

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Absolutely, but your answer pointed me to the mistake I did there, I bound straight to the CollectionViewSource instead of it's View property, this works great. You wan't to submit this as a answer perhaps? Also when you do it this way do you use the sorting on the CollectionViewSource or it's View property. Filter seems to have to be applied straight to the View property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the approach outlined in the remarks section of the documentation of the `CollectionView` class:

> To create a collection view for a collection that only implements `IEnumerable`, create a `CollectionViewSource` object, add your collection to the `Source` property, and get the collection view from the `View` property.

This approach is the equivalent to `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`, i.e. you will use the retrieved `View` just the same:

- You bind it to the UI
- You use it to filter
- You use it to sort